# Backbone fetching a collection using callbacks vs promises

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, promise, backbone.js-collections

I have a Location collection, and I have back a JSON response from the serve r on fetch including the root title with format:

```
{'locations':[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "address": 'first address'
},{
  "id": 2,
  "address": 'second address'
}
]}
```

I've read everywhere that is best practice to use promise's methods over backbone success and error callbacks but here is the thing. I have override the parse method on the Location collection to return the array, but it appears that using the promises methods the parse method isn't called at all. So for example:

```
var Locations = new Backbone.Collection.extend({...})
var locations = new Locations()
locations.fetch().then(function(response){
console.log(response)
})
```

returns an Object literal with property locations which has the value of the Array of locations. But if I use

```
locations.fetch({ 
success: function(response){
console.log(response)
}
})
```

I get the wanted behavior, that is the object with constructor Locations and all the models in it.

Plus if I remove the root title of the JSON response on the backend and remove the parse method override on the collection, with the promise methods I'm getting an object with constructor Array, while with the success callback I'm getting an object with constructor Locations.

So my question is, if it is better to use the promise's methods how to adopt them with the similar behavior as the success and error callbacks?

Requsted update:

Here is the parse function in the Locations collections

```
var Locations = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
parse: function(response){
return response['locations']
}
})
```

Comment: Can you show us how you've overwritten the parse method?

Comment: @Bergi I've updated the question with your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the collection directly:

```
locations.fetch().then(function(){
    console.log(locations);
})
```

---

The `fetch` method returns the jqXHR promise that makes the request, so it returns the raw response received from the server. The promise doesn't know about the parsing of the response.

The reason that passing a `success` callback as an option to `fetch` worked for you is: (See [Collection.fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) documentation)

> The **options** hash takes `success` and `error` callbacks which will both be passed `(collection, response, options)` as arguments.

So if use pass a `success` callback to `fetch`, the first argument is actually `collection`, not `response`.